# change div style with from my javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

can some one help me by adding some some code on my code that works for me
here is what i need ..

my full code is here http://jsfiddle.net/2urmku1h/

here i need change

```
<div style="display:none;">Change style of this div to Block fro js above</div>
```

and here is some of my js code that is in head section i need it some how to work

```
function startChecking() {
    secondsleft -= 1e3;
    document.querySelector(".load_video").innerHTML = "Please Wait.. " + Math.abs(secondsleft / 1e3) + " Seconds";
    if (secondsleft == 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        document.querySelector(".load_video").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector(".frame_src").style.display = "";
        document.querySelector(".frame_src").src = document.querySelector(".frame_src").getAttribute("data-src")
    }
}

function startschedule() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    secondsleft = threshold;
    document.querySelector(".load_video").innerHTML = "Please Wait.. " + Math.abs(secondsleft / 1e3) + " Seconds";
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        startChecking()
    }, 1e3)
}

function resetTimer() {
    startschedule()
}
var timeout, interval;
var threshold = 1e4;
var secondsleft = threshold;
window.onload = function() {
    startschedule()
}
```

what i need is, if i clicked on one of video links it will stop countdown whether it's 5 seconds left or what ever, it will stop countdown and hiide this div `<div class="load_video"></div>`

and show the iframe. but i want it like, when i clicked one of that buttons it does hide load_video div and show iframe but i want it also it change style of this div `<div style="display:none;">Change style of this div to Block fro js above</div>`  display to block.

hope you guys understand

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways in which you could select the div element in which you are referencing. For simplicity, suppose you add an id to the div...

```
<div id="modifyMe" style="display:none;">Change style of this div to Block fro js above</div>
```

...then add the following code where you would like the change the div to display block.

jQuery solution:

```
$('#modifyMe').show();
```

Without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById('modifyMe').style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: thanks you for your answer. yes sir i know but i don't know where do i add the code between my codes as you see in head section. will you do it for me if it's not much for you sir?

Comment: and maybe you didn't read that where i said i need it to change style when i clicked on one of that video buttons. not like, when countdown is 0 then it will change style to block. or if it's possible to do both, when countdown is 0 then change style to block also when i click on video button

Comment: @student3979923 I edited my answer. You want to stick the code within the click function for your video links. Here is a modified jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2urmku1h/2/ Look for my comment in your html "/* I added it here :) */"

Comment: thank yyou so much sir. you did it on click when i click video button. but is it possible you make it also when countdown is 0? what i mean is it will be better also when countdown is 0 then change style to block. leave that click like that as you made it i need it too

Comment: @student3979923 I added it to your startChecking function http://jsfiddle.net/2urmku1h/3/ see my other comment :)

Comment: wow. thank you so much sir. my head almost blow up thinking of how i do since 5 hours i am trying :D . but thank you sir you are life saver. that's all i needed. thanks again